# Primefaces fileupload ajax (growl)

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

i have the file upload using primefaces, in advanced mode,

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload(event)}"
                                      mode="advanced" 
                                      update="messages"
                                      sizeLimit="100000000" 
                                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|doc|docx|txt|pdf)$/"
                                      auto="true"/>

                        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
```

But i want to add a few nice finishing touches, like i have seen examples that use growl, that pops up a message saying success etc once completed, but am unsure on how to do this with glassfish, and do it on completion of the file being uploaded

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You have what you're asking for implemented in Primefaces showcase. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf

Comment: Yes the upload works perfectly fine, i am just trying to figure out how to use `growl` to display a message such as upload successful

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue, my bean wasn't configured correctly thats all :)

EDIT :

Looked into the glassfish console and saw it was not calling the event caller, so it was skipping this enter section, i just simply changed the method call in the xhtml, and make sure the bean was correct, if anyone wants to see the bean just post a comment and ill add it :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: In case this could help people in the future, how specifically was it misconfigured?

Comment: @user1924104 what was the old managed bean configuration, which changes did you made in order to solve the problem? Please add all this info so future users (and visitors) could learn from this experience. It would be good to add some additional info in the question too.

Comment: @user1924104 What Luiggi said :)